# How can I reserve ip address in new azure portal with resource manager (and not classic azure portal)?

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I know I can reserve ip addresses using New-AzureReservedIP commandlet in classic azure portal after looking at this link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

But my resources are in the new resource manager portal and they don't have equivalents in the classic portal.

I thought I would find similar command in the new azure portal after looking at this link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/#public-ip-addresses

I could not find the equivalent of the above command let. Then I found following text in the above link:

*Note:
Even when you set the allocation method to static, you cannot specify the actual IP address assigned to the public IP resource. Instead, it gets allocated from a pool of available IP addresses in the Azure location the resource is created in.*

Does this mean I can not reserve an IP address in the new azure portal with resource manager? If it is possible, then please list the azure commandlet sequence.

The following link talked about reserving the ip address in the classic portal and making them work in the new portal. But that is not my use case, hence I can't use it:
[Reserved IP's for Azure Resource Manager based Virtual machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622975/reserved-ips-for-azure-resource-manager-based-virtual-machines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress PowerShell command.

```
New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName GroupName -Name IPName -AllocationMethod Static/Dynamic
```

MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603620.aspx), you can also do it as part of an ARM template, I have examples [here](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/07/how-to-assign-a-public-static-ip-address-in-azure-using-azure-resource-manager/).

When you create a NIC using New-AzureRmNetworkInterface command attach the IP to the NIC by specifying the -PublicIpAddress IPName parameter.

MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619370.aspx).

Comment: The above command talks about creating new IP. Can I use the same (or another) command to keep the existing IP in a given resource group?

Comment: If I get a new ip address with New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress for a resource in a given resource group, once I delete that resource group, would I still have that ip address so that when I re-create that resource group, I can re-use the same ip address for the resource in that group?

Comment: If you delete the resource group you also delete all the resources inside it, including the PublicIP address. You can create your PublicIPs in a different resource group if you plan on keeping them. If you make the AllocationMethod dynamic the allocated IP address will change when you attach or remove them from a NIC but if you make it static it will always stay the same.

Comment: But if I create public IPs (say x.y.z.a) in resource group A, can I assign that ip address (x.y.z.a) to a resource in resource group B? Will it work?

Comment: Yes it will work, they can be in different resource groups but must be in the same location and subscription.